# Comparing arguments - wrong types

Tags: record-type

I have a custom object with a number of record types. Now, in my controller, I want to write an if statement to check whether the current record is a certain record type.

I wrote:

```
        if (RecordType.Name == 'Recordtype1'){
            variable1= 'value1';
        }else{
            variable1 = 'value2';
        }
```

The problem seems to be that :

> Comparison arguments must be compatible types:
>   Schema.SObjectField,String

So I assume the problem is that `Recordtype1` is a `String` and `RecordType.Name` returns an `SObjectField`.

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks, Lily

Comment: Did you try to cast `RecordType.Name` on a `String` ?

Comment: how would I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Lily,

you cannot directly use RecordType.Name

you can query the RecordType to get the name using the RecordTypeId on the custom object record and then compare the name against a string.

something like

```
RecordType rt = [Select Name from RecordType where SobjectType = 'CustomObject' AND Id = :cObj.RecordTypeId limit 1];
if (rt.Name == 'Recordtype1'){
    variable1= 'value1';
}else{
    variable1 = 'value2';
}
```

additional references :

[What would be the best approach to get the recordtype id](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11968/what-would-be-the-best-approach-to-get-the-recordtype-id)

[Why am I not getting the Record Type name when I use RecordType.Name](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13567/why-am-i-not-getting-the-record-type-name-when-i-use-recordtype-name)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [relationship queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm), if you are querying your custom object in your controller, you can include the record type name in the query:

```
select Id, Name, ..., RecordType.Name from MyCustomObject__c where ...
```

and check the name directly in your logic:

```
MyCustomObject__c myObject = ...;
if (myObject.RecordType.Name == 'Recordtype1') {
    variable1 = 'value1';
} else {
    variable1 = 'value2';
}
```

In the code posted in the question, `RecordType.Name` is being interpreted as an SObjectField token because `RecordType` is an SObjectType token known to the compiler. These tokens are useful when writing code that works with a variety of objects, but unfortunately are easy to accidentally reference in code with confusing results.