# Trigger to update account field base on case record type

Tags: apex, trigger, developer

I am trying to make it so that if a user opens a case with the "**Customer Save**" record type that it updates the `LE_Status__c` field on the account object. I keep getting error

> Comparison arguments must be compativle types: SObject:RecordType,
>   String at line 4 column 13.

I am learning apex so if your answer includes code could you also add an explanation so I can learn from my mistake?

My code is below.

```
Trigger UpdateLEStatus on Case (after insert) {
    Set<Id> UpdatedCaseIds = new Set<Id>(); 
    for (Case c: Trigger.new) {
        if (c.RecordType == 'Customer Save') {
            UpdatedCaseIds.add(c.id);
        }    
    }
    List<Account> AccountForUpdating = [SELECT LE_Status__c
                                                       FROM Account
                                                       WHERE Case IN: UpdatedCaseIds];
    for (Account item: AccountForUpdating) {
        item.LE_Status__c = 'Red';
    }
    update AccountForUpdating;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare **Record Type** with a **String** , since both are different data types you are getting this error.

you have to either use

- `RecordType.Name` - which you have to query for the record or
- `RecordTypeId` which will be there in the context variable

to check/compare the type.

so your code will look like this..

```
Trigger UpdateLEStatus on Case (after insert) {
    Set<Id> UpdatedCaseIds = new Set<Id>(); 

    Id recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.RecordTypeInfosByName.get('Customer Save').RecordTypeId;

    for (Case c: Trigger.new) {
        if (c.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId) {
            UpdatedCaseIds.add(c.id);
        }    
    }
    List<Account> AccountForUpdating = [SELECT LE_Status__c
                                                       FROM Account
                                                       WHERE Case IN: UpdatedCaseIds];
    for (Account item: AccountForUpdating) {
        item.LE_Status__c = 'Red';
    }
    update AccountForUpdating;
}
```

here's some other related discussions which you can refer as well

[How to find current record's RecordType name](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45847/how-to-find-current-records-recordtype-name)

[Why am I not getting the Record Type name when I use RecordType.Name](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13567/why-am-i-not-getting-the-record-type-name-when-i-use-recordtype-name)